# How to switch fragments using previous and next buttons?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've 3 fragment classes. When I'm in 1st fragment class having two buttons i.e "next" and "previous", the "previous" button should remain unclickable and then on clicking "next" button the fragment class should switch to 2nd fragment class and similarly on clicking "next" button it should switch to 3rd fragment class but remaining "next" button as unclickable.

My problem is none of the buttons work when it is clicked. When I'm in first page neither "next" button switch to 2nd fragment class nor "previous" button remain unclickable.

Right now to check, I'm changing the text color of buttons as white so as it make feel that the button is unclickable.

```
 public class HomeFormViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 FirstPage.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
 SecondPage.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
 ThirdPage.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

Button button1, button2;
public FrameLayout frameLayout;

public FirstPage firstPage;
public SecondPage secondPage;
public ThirdPage thirdPage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_form_view);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    button1 = findViewById(R.id.pre_button);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.nxt_button);

    frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);

    firstPage = new FirstPage();
    secondPage = new SecondPage();
    thirdPage = new ThirdPage();

    setFragment(firstPage); // To display first fragment

    if (currentFragment() instanceof FirstPage){

        Toast.makeText(this, "You are in first page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        button1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.LightGrey));
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setFragment(secondPage);
            }
        });
    }


     if (currentFragment() instanceof SecondPage){

        Toast.makeText(this, "You are in second page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setFragment(thirdPage);
            }
        });
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setFragment(firstPage);
            }
        });
    }

  if (currentFragment() instanceof ThirdPage){

        Toast.makeText(this, "You are in third page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        button2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.LightGrey));
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setFragment(secondPage);
            }
        });
    }

}

public Fragment currentFragment() {

    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout);
}

private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

Comment: Please try to check conditions of first and third fragments inside on click listeners and perform according to conditions there is no use of multiple setOnClickListeners() in every if conditions use only two and use condtions inside clickfunctions

Comment: @Ayush Katuwal I suggest that first of all remove all conditions that you have written to make click listener in the onCreate method. 
Then inside on click method of a button check your fragment conditions to perform previous or next action.

Answer (score 2):

Your methods of instance checking are at wrong place. When you call setFragment in onCreate it takes some time to replace the fragments in framelayout. Secondly, your check conditions will not run every time you replace a fragment. Also, you must add fragment for first time and then call replace.

Button clicks should be something like this:

```
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (currentFragment() instanceof FirstPage){
//Some code here
                   }else if (currentFragment() instanceof SecondPage){
//Some code here
    }
            }
        });
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (currentFragment() instanceof FirstPage){
//Some code here
                   }else if (currentFragment() instanceof SecondPage){
//Some code here

    }
            }
        });
```

I am not good at formatting. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rushi M Thakker. I understand what I commit mistake.

Comment: Great!! Good luck and happy coding